Do TCP sequence numbers increase by the Ethernet frame size, or tcp payload size?
Have Googled this but it's difficult to word this without getting irrelevant results.
The TCP sequence number increases by "how many bytes were sent".
Does this mean literally the entire Ethernet frame size (including IP header), or just the TCP payload size?


Does this mean literally the entire Ethernet frame size (including IP header), or just the TCP payload size?

TCP is not aware of the Ethernet frame. Nor need there be an Ethernet frame - and the TCP packet may be transported over different links, such as SLIP, PPP, Ethernet and WiFi - which each have their own header. So the actual frame size on the wire may vary widely for the same packet.

Understood. So does the sequence number increase by the TCP payload size, or TCP header + payload size?

Data, e.g. payload.
